# Let $U(a,t) = \{a\} \cup [t, \infty)$ where $a,t \in \Bbb R.$ Show that the generated space is not Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

> Let $U(a,t) = \{a\} \cup [t, \infty)$ where $a,t \in \Bbb R.$ The collection of these sets forms a basis for some topology $\tau$ on $\Bbb R$. Show that the generated space is not Hausdorff.

Let $x,y \in \Bbb R$. We need to show that $O_x \cap O_y = \emptyset$. I am confused about what are these sets $O_x$ and $O_y$? Are they just unions and intersections of the basis elements $U(a,t)$ or how should I express them? I don't think I have $O_x=U(x,t)$ and $O_y=U(y,s)$ for $t, s \in \Bbb R$?

Even if I had the intersection $$(\{x\} \cup [t, \infty)) \cap (\{y\} \cup [s, \infty))  $$ is neve non-empty as it's at least one of the intervals?

Comment: Every two basic open sets intersect. It follows that any two non-empty open sets intersect. Such a space is sometimes called “anti-Hausdorff “ or irreducible.

Comment: See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space) e.g.

Comment: Recall that the open sets are precisely the unions of all basic open sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N_0$ and $N_1$ be neighborhoods of $0$ and $1$ respectively. Then $N_0\supset U(a,t)$ and $N_1\supset U(b,s)$ for some numbers $a$, $b$, $s$, and $t$ such that $0\in U(a,t)$ and that $b\in U(b,s)$. But then $N_0\cap N_1\ne\emptyset$, since$$\max\{s,t\}\in U(a,t)\cap U(b,s)\subset N_0\cap N_1.$$

Answer (score 2):

> Let $x,y \in \Bbb R$. We need to show that $O_x \cap O_y = \emptyset$.

No, that is not what you need to show.

Remember to always follow the definitions. You need to show that the space is **not Hausdorff**.

Remember, by definition, a space $(X, \tau)$ is Hausdorff if, for every pair of points $x,y\in X$, there exist two open sets $O_x$ and $O_y$ such that $x\in O_x, y\in O_y$ and $O_x\cap O_y=\emptyset$.

In your case, you must prove the space is **not** Hausdorff, and you can do that by proving the above statement is false, or in other words, you must find some pair of points $x,y\in\mathbb R$ so that every open neighborhood of $x$ must intersect every open neighborhood of point $y$.